# Excel Advance Sumif formula

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

I have a formula to look through a list and if it contains a specific string add the cells beside it.

```
Cell D5 = "String1" 'for example
=SUMIF($A$4:$A$250,"*- "&D5&"*",$C$4:$C$250)
```

The problem I face is when I search for the "*-String1*" there are times where there are multiple strings I'm searching for - example:

[image]

with the above formula it would add 300 for each string1, string2, and string4 cells and adds 400 for both string1 and string3

The formula I am looking for is to search for "*-string?*" and divide by cell next to it the number of "*- *" there are in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D5,$A$4:$A$24)),$C$4:$C$24/(LEN($A$4:$A$24)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$4:$A$24,"- ","x")))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I need to be able separate each string in it's own row not in a single row + your math is wrong it should add up to 2100 not 5400

Comment: @BrettNelson I swear I have answered this before but can't find it.  See edit.

Comment: I thought I asked this question before but I couldn't find it either but that you again for answering